# jQuery checkbox: change from a click method to something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery method (function?) on a checkbox that executes when the checkbox is clicked

```
click.function() {
 // blah blah
}
```

But now I want the checkbox to be checked by default...how do I make the function run automatically (without waiting for the checkbox to be clicked on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#checkboxId').click(function() {
    // blah blah
}).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is better to abstract the logic out to server-side instead of programmatically clicking the checkbox on the client. What I mean is, pre-select the checkbox server-side by writing out the attribute `checked="true"` or `checked="checked"` (depending on doctype) and then also perform the function on load.

What if user clicks on the checkbox before the JS kicks in? You might also want to disable the checkbox until your JS is fully loaded.

Comment: I think the attribute is either Boolean (HTML) so the presence of, simply, `checked` is sufficient, or, in XHTML, it should be `checked="checked"`...but I can't think of a reference with which to conclusively assert this. Sorry.